# Passing and parsing SqlDataReader to javascript - good practice?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql, google-maps

I have a Google map on my web site which I need its markers to be updated by timer.
My solution is:

1. Make a SQL query to the server DB.
2. Get the SqlDataReader.
3. Pass it to the JS code (which manage the map) by a function (`RegisterStartupScript`?)
4. The JS clears all existing markers and set new ones according to the SqlDataReader data.

I don't want the whole page to be refreshed when this is done.
Your opinion?

Comment: I wouldn't create data access via javascript code, as this could potentially open your site up to various attacks such as SQL injection and XSS attacks. If you are using ASP.NET MVC, you could use a partial page inside your view that hits an action on a controller every N seconds (enforced using javascript), and returns data via a jsonresult (accessed using your sqldatareader, ideally using a repository to abstract data access).

Comment: @ianaldo21 I think your comment is worthy of being an answer.

Comment: @tyrongower Your right, I was thinking the same thing as I was writing the "comment" and running out of characters :P

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't create data access via javascript code, as this could potentially open your site up to various attacks such as SQL injection and XSS attacks. If you are using ASP.NET MVC, you could use a partial page inside your view that hits an action on a controller every N seconds (enforced using javascript), and returns data via a jsonresult (accessed using your sqldatareader, ideally using a repository to abstract data access).

Comment: Do you mean putting the whole map inside an `asp:UpdatePanel`?

Comment: Apologies, my knowledge of asp.net web forms has waned a little bit. But you could use the Jquery Ajax API to make a call to a method on your code behind, and return the data to update a div containing the map, no need to use an updatepanel, this should help get you started: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Can I do it the other way? i.e. A timer in the code behind will make an SQL query and send the data to the map to parse?